# How to target individual componants in an imported svg file?

Tags: html, svg

I have an svg file of a person, where each layer is a part of the body, like arm, leg, face, etc...
In my html file I import that svg file. So is there a way I can target the right leg (for example) only in the imported svg file and only transform that?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the structure of the svg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually SVGs have standard tags such as `path` for each path,

as with default elements you can attach `class` selectors.

That said to select individual path I use something like:

```
document.querySelector('path.st1');//in JS
```

Comment: If I import the svg through img tag, how do I do this?

Comment: yes that's true;  as a workaround, you could  insert it directly in the html; doing this you can manipulate it in any way